# How to have  colored manual pages in  gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, documentation, manpage

When I switched to tty I noticed manpages look different by using some color scheme. How to make it to gnome-terminal?

**Update**: Here is [a solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119/colors-in-man-pages), I found at Unix stackExchange site.

Comment: This question is very vague. What are you asking?

Comment: I guess what you are asking is coloured like pattern in normal gnome terminal.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't know it, but I found something here:
http://www.tuxarena.com/2012/04/tutorial-colored-man-pages-how-it-works/

Instructions from the above link:

Edit your .bashrc file and add the following lines:

```
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$(printf '\e[01;31m') # enter blinking mode - red
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$(printf '\e[01;35m') # enter double-bright mode - bold, magenta
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$(printf '\e[0m') # turn off all appearance modes (mb, md, so, us)
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$(printf '\e[0m') # leave standout mode    
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$(printf '\e[01;33m') # enter standout mode - yellow
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$(printf '\e[0m') # leave underline mode
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$(printf '\e[04;36m') # enter underline mode - cyan
```

Next, start a new terminal session or enter the command `source ~./bashrc` in your current terminal.

Answer (score 10):

You can have coloured man pages using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install most
export PAGER="most"
```

Now check your man pages by

```
man ls
```

[image]

Comment: If you only want to use `most` as the pager for `man` then you can alias this via `alias man="man -P most"`.

Comment: @DrewNoakes or set `MANPAGER` instead of `PAGER`.

Comment: If you only want to use `most` for its colouring of `man` pages, I'd suggest that you just [setup colours for `less` instead](http://askubuntu.com/a/834107/478705).

Answer (score 2):

Without needing to install `most`, you can configure `less` to look like this:

[image: Coloured man page example]

Add the following in your `~.bashrc':

```
# Have less display colours
# from: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Color_output_in_console#man
export LESS_TERMCAP_mb=$'\e[1;31m'     # begin bold
export LESS_TERMCAP_md=$'\e[1;33m'     # begin blink
export LESS_TERMCAP_so=$'\e[01;44;37m' # begin reverse video
export LESS_TERMCAP_us=$'\e[01;37m'    # begin underline
export LESS_TERMCAP_me=$'\e[0m'        # reset bold/blink
export LESS_TERMCAP_se=$'\e[0m'        # reset reverse video
export LESS_TERMCAP_ue=$'\e[0m'        # reset underline
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use [Oh My Zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/) you can add `colored-man-pages` to the `plugins` array of your `.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way would be a manual one by Going through the Edit menu of Gnome Terminal in Menu Bar , then In Profile Preferences as here in image. You can try and play around to suite your needs.

[image]

Another is a process explained [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/solarized-must-have-color-paletter-for.html).Though explained for 11.04 version , check out its [homepage](http://ethanschoonover.com/solarized) for further info.